# Regex only matching last occurrence

Tags: java, regex

My regex is:

`genres\":\[(?=.*name\":\"(.*?)\"}(?=.*\"homepage))`

And my target is:

```
{
    "adult":false,
    "backdrop_path":"/b9OVFl48ZV2oTLzACSwBpNrCUhJ.jpg",
    "belongs_to_collection": {
        "id":135468,
        "name":"G.I. Joe (Live-Action Series)",
        "poster_path":"/5LtZM6zLB2TDbdIaOC5uafjYZY1.jpg",
        "backdrop_path":"/m3ip0ci0TnX0ATUxpweqElYCeq4.jpg"
    },
    "budget":185000000,
    "genres":[
        {
            "id":28,
            "name":"Action"
        },
        {
            "id":12,
            "name":"Adventure"
        },
        {
            "id":878,
            "name":"Science Fiction"
        },
        {
            "id":53,
            "name":"Thriller"
        }
    ],
    "homepage":"http://www.gijoemovie.com",
    "id":72559,
    "imdb_id":"tt1583421",
    "original_title":"G.I. Joe: Retaliation",
    "overview":"Framed for crimes against the country, the G.I. Joe team is terminated by Presidential order. This forces the G.I. Joes into not only fighting their mortal enemy Cobra; they are forced to contend with threats from within the government that jeopardize their very existence.",
    "popularity":11.7818680433822,
    "poster_path":"/swk1AHwPvIJv8NUFM1qpFuaT642.jpg",
    "production_companies":[
        {
            "name":"Paramount Pictures",
            "id":4
        },
        {
            "name":"Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer (MGM)",
            "id":8411
            }
    ],
    "production_countries":[
        {
            "iso_3166_1":"US",
            "name":"United States of America"
        }
    ],
    "release_date":"2013-03-29",
    "revenue":371876278,
    "runtime":110,
    "spoken_languages":[
        {
            "iso_639_1":"en",
            "name":"English"
        }
    ],
    "status":"Released",
    "tagline":"GI JOE IS NO MORE",
    "title":"G.I. Joe: Retaliation",
    "vote_average":5.4,
    "vote_count":1806
}
```

I know that it's JSON, and I should use a JSON class or something better than Regex to work with it, but, in this project I'm limited to Regex.

I'm testing my Regex with http://regexhero.net/tester/ and I only get `Thriller`, when I should get `Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller`, all of them.

PS: I'm using Java and java.util.regex

```
List<String> generos = new ArrayList<>();

Matcher filter = Pattern.compile("genres\":\\[(?=.*name\":\"(.*?)\"}(?=.*\"homepage))").matcher(response);

        while (filter.find()) {
            generos.add(filter.group(1));
        }
```

The code is totally fine, the only problem is in the regex. Just try this regex in any Regex Tester, and you will see that it only gets the LAST occurrence, but I need ALL of them.

Comment: Why on earth would you not use a JSON parser???

Comment: Why are you "limited to Regex?"

Comment: The teacher said so...

Comment: I think the problem is in the implementation of the regex, not in the regex itself.

Comment: Implementation? Explain yourself, please.

Comment: I think he means, that your regex is fine, but you are just using it incorrectly. Can you show us the code when you are actually using the regex?

Comment: Edited, the code is fine. The only problem is the regex!

Comment: @adback03 no, the regex is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(?<!^)(?:genres|\G)[^]]*?"name":"(.*?)"
```

`\G` essentially matches the location where the previous match ended (or start of string if you haven't matched anything yet). [[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html)]

Thus, since `\G` can match start-of-string (but we don't want that), first make sure we're not at the start of the string with the negative lookbehind `(?<!^)`.

Then, find either "genres" or `\G` (the place where your matching previously left off), and start looking for "name" following that. The quantifier in `[^]]*?` is made lazy with `?` so it will stop when it finds the first "name" instead of continuing greedily until it passes the others and finds only the last one.

Your desired text will be captured in group #1.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in regexhero:

```
(?<=genres[^]]{1,200})\"name\":\"[^"]+\"
```

`[^]]` will ensure that you stay within the genres array.

Comment: That regex won't compile in Java. Lookbehind assertions need to be finite.

Comment: Thank you. I edited your regex and now it's getting all I want. `(?<=genres[^]]+)\"name\":\"(.*?)\"` in RegexHero.

Comment: As @Tim Pietzcker said. `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 14 [...]`

Comment: @TimPietzcker I modified the regex to give it a finite length. Not very elegant, but it should work...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's a terrible idea to try and parse a decidedly non-regular format like JSON with a regular expression. I have no idea why you would be required to try so by your teacher, unless he/she wanted to make you find out the hard way how *not* to use a regex...

That said, you can't do this with a single regex, at least not if the number of `genres` isn't always fixed, which it's unlikely to be.

You can do it in two steps:

First, match the `genres` list with the following regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\"genres\":\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]");
```

Then use this regex on the match result of the previous regex:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\"name\":\"([^\"]*)\"");
```

(taking the results from `.group(1)` of each match).

Comment: Like that? `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\"genres\":\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]");` `filter = regex.matcher("\"name\":\"([^\"]*)\"");`

Comment: > _"you can't do this with a single regex"_ - What about `(?<!^)(?:genres|\G)[^]]*?"name":"(.*?)"`?  ( http://fiddle.re/hy0w8 )

Comment: Wiseguy, you rocks. Please post, and I can mark your answer as the accepted. And please, explain your magic. :)

Comment: @Wiseguy: Ah right, I forgot that Java is one of the few regex engines that supports the "anchor at the end of the previous match" feature. Good solution!